# How do I make my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop look like this?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, lts

How to make my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop look like this?

[image: Ubuntu Desktop]

Comment: Nope. https://www.deepin.org/en/dde/ is it.

Comment: Glad that you liked Deepin. But the screenshot you posted shows just a standard vanilla Ubuntu installation with the Ubuntu Dock moved to the bottom. So the other question question precisely deals with the issue raised in your question.

Comment: @pomsky Totally agree with you . I thought he talk about Dock and after write my answer to tell him how to change dock like that but i become so surprise because he ask about something and need another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might give Deepin a shot, looks like it's what you're after:
https://www.deepin.org/en/dde/

Comment: Ummm. This is perfect. Thanks so much. If I ever have an issue in installing or customizing Ubuntu I shall ask here. You guys are very helpful

Comment: Please upvote my question so others can benefit in future.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

You have to Install `GNOME Tweaks`, How ? There are many ways 

1 - Open [Ubuntu Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHZ7h.png) and just write `GNOME Tweaks` , Then install it.

 2 - Using termial , just write :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

**Second**

There are Two options :

1 - Go to [GNOME Shell extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) , Then look for [Dash to dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/), Then Enable it but first you must have `install browser extension` as mentioned in the page .

2 - Go Ubuntu software and search for [dash to dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbBmk.png) , then install it.

**Third**

Restart your session , How? just `logout` and `login` again.

After that , Go to `GNOME Tweaks` and Enable [Dash to dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GXbQ.png) extension.
You can also change settings of your Dock , How ? Just Click on this [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQPV7.png).

If you want to change whole theme , icons , ...etc , I prefer to [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHzGYG2XvMI)

Hope that helps you, Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a ton. But Deepin seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can install the dock to dash extension from the ubuntu software center then from the setting change the position to bottom, and for the icons and themes you have to install the tweak tool also form ubuntu software center, then check this website [gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/) choose your favorite theme and icons download it and in your home directory create .themes and .icons folders and place the extracted files from the download in it, then back to the tweak tool choose the theme and the icons theme.
for further help heck this video to make Ubuntu looks like MacOS
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHzGYG2XvMI